# How to preload my nav bar's graphics

Tags: css, web, navigation

I created and coded my own css navigation bar (inspired by apple, if that helps you visualize), that means i have dynamic buttons with 4 states that i manage with a css stylesheet.  I only have two graphics, one with the button states, and another with the stylized "text".

However, i'de like to make it so that the nab bar's graphics are preloaded in my webpages.

1) is this possible ?

2) is it useful ?

3) if yes to both questions what would be the code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really see the point in preloading those images. If the images are static and always refer to the same file without parameters, they will be cached anyway by the browser and only loaded the first time a visitor comes to your site (unless you prevent caching with some fancy http header settings), and served out of the clients browser cache on further requests. Do you have an example of your navigation to look at?

if you are concerned about loading times your could quite easy have a navigation similar to apple.com by using css3-gradients for the background, border radius for the outer container and only declare a background-image in you IE stylesheet as fallback option, so modern browsers wont requests the IE background pattern.

Add some 1px offset text-shadow to give your navigation some 3d look.

Comment: yes, i have an example, go to Apple.com my menu bar uses about the same technique adapted to fit xhtml 1.0 traditional.Look at their code if you want, that'll give you an idea of what i have. I may edit my post to show you my own code, but u'll have to ask for it : D

Answer (score 2):

You can preload images either by using JavaScript, or by inserting img tags early on in the page with styling to hide them.

JavaScript example:

```
<script>
image = new Image();
image.src = '/path/to/image.png';
</script>
```

You'll need to do the "image = ...", "image.src = ..." for each image you want to preload. This code will load the image into the browser's cache.

HTML/CSS example:

```
<img src="/path/to/image.png" style="display: none;" />
```

The above will load the image, but won't display it on the page.